# How can the if-else conditions be more optimally coded?

Tags: ios, if-statement, conditional-statements, swift4

```
func validateAllField (array : [FormPreferencesModel]?) -> Bool {
    let isEmailFieldVisible = self.isEmailFieldVisible(array)
        let isCustomFieldVisible = self.isCustomFieldVisible(array)
        let isCompanyFieldVisible = self.isCompanyFieldVisible(array)
        let purpose = getSelectedPurpose()
        if purpose.captureGuestImage == true {
            if (self.emailTextField.tag == 101) {
                if (isEmailFieldVisible == false) {
                    if (!self.userName.isEmpty && self.userName.count > 2) && (!customField.isEmpty) && (self.visitorImageView.isHidden == false) && (self.visitorImageView.image != nil) {
                        activateNextButton()
                        return true
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!self.userName.isEmpty && self.userName.count > 2) && (!self.userEmailId.isEmpty && self.isValidEmail(email: self.userEmailId)) && (!customField.isEmpty) && (self.visitorImageView.isHidden == false) && (self.visitorImageView.image != nil) {
                        activateNextButton()
                        return true
                    }
                }

                if (isCustomFieldVisible == false) {
                    if (!self.userName.isEmpty && self.userName.count > 2) && (!self.userEmailId.isEmpty && self.isValidEmail(email: self.userEmailId)) && (self.visitorImageView.isHidden == false) && (self.visitorImageView.image != nil) {
                        activateNextButton()
                        return true
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!self.userName.isEmpty && self.userName.count > 2) && (!self.userEmailId.isEmpty && self.isValidEmail(email: self.userEmailId)) && (!customField.isEmpty) && (self.visitorImageView.isHidden == false) && (self.visitorImageView.image != nil) {
                        activateNextButton()
                        return true
                    }
                }
                if (isEmailFieldVisible == false && isCustomFieldVisible == false) {
                    if (!self.userName.isEmpty && self.userName.count > 2) && (self.visitorImageView.isHidden == false) && (self.visitorImageView.image != nil) {
                        activateNextButton()
                        return true
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (isCompanyFieldVisible == false) {
                    if (!self.userName.isEmpty && self.userName.count > 2) && (!customField.isEmpty) && (self.visitorImageView.isHidden == false) && (self.visitorImageView.image != nil) {
                        activateNextButton()
                        return true
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!self.userName.isEmpty && self.userName.count > 2) && (!self.userEmailId.isEmpty && self.userEmailId.count >= 2) && (!customField.isEmpty) && (self.visitorImageView.isHidden == false) && (self.visitorImageView.image != nil) {
                        activateNextButton()
                        return true
                    }
                }

                if (isCustomFieldVisible == false) {
                    if (!self.userName.isEmpty && self.userName.count > 2) && (!self.userEmailId.isEmpty && self.userEmailId.count >= 2) && (self.visitorImageView.isHidden == false) && (self.visitorImageView.image != nil) {
                        activateNextButton()
                        return true
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!self.userName.isEmpty && self.userName.count > 2) && (!self.userEmailId.isEmpty && self.userEmailId.count >= 2) && (!customField.isEmpty) && (self.visitorImageView.isHidden == false) && (self.visitorImageView.image != nil) {
                        activateNextButton()
                        return true
                    }
                }
                if (isCompanyFieldVisible == false && isCustomFieldVisible == false) {
                    if (!self.userName.isEmpty && self.userName.count > 2) && (self.visitorImageView.isHidden == false) && (self.visitorImageView.image != nil) {
                        activateNextButton()
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (self.emailTextField.tag == 101) {
                if (isEmailFieldVisible == false) {
                    if (!self.userName.isEmpty && self.userName.count > 2) && (!customField.isEmpty) {
                        activateNextButton()
                        return true
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!self.userName.isEmpty && self.userName.count > 2) && (!self.userEmailId.isEmpty && self.isValidEmail(email: self.userEmailId)) && (!customField.isEmpty) {
                        activateNextButton()
                        return true
                    }
                }

                if (isCustomFieldVisible == false) {
                    if (!self.userName.isEmpty && self.userName.count > 2) && (!self.userEmailId.isEmpty && self.isValidEmail(email: self.userEmailId)) {
                        activateNextButton()
                        return true
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!self.userName.isEmpty && self.userName.count > 2) && (!self.userEmailId.isEmpty && self.isValidEmail(email: self.userEmailId)) && (!customField.isEmpty) {
                        activateNextButton()
                        return true
                    }
                }
                if (isEmailFieldVisible == false && isCustomFieldVisible == false) {
                    if (!self.userName.isEmpty && self.userName.count > 2) {
                        activateNextButton()
                        return true
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (isCompanyFieldVisible == false) {
                    if (!self.userName.isEmpty && self.userName.count > 2) && (!customField.isEmpty) {
                        activateNextButton()
                        return true
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!self.userName.isEmpty && self.userName.count > 2) && (!self.userEmailId.isEmpty && self.userEmailId.count >= 2) && (!customField.isEmpty) {
                        activateNextButton()
                        return true
                    }
                }

                if (isCustomFieldVisible == false) {
                    if (!self.userName.isEmpty && self.userName.count > 2) && (!self.userEmailId.isEmpty && self.userEmailId.count >= 2) {
                        activateNextButton()
                        return true
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!self.userName.isEmpty && self.userName.count > 2) && (!self.userEmailId.isEmpty && self.userEmailId.count >= 2) && (!customField.isEmpty) {
                        activateNextButton()
                        return true
                    }
                }
                if (isCompanyFieldVisible == false && isCustomFieldVisible == false) {
                    if (!self.userName.isEmpty && self.userName.count > 2) {
                        activateNextButton()
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

I just want to reduce the code complexity by more efficiently implementing the `if-else` conditions.  There are three types of fields which require validation. All of the conditions are mandatory; is there a way to implement this more efficiently?

Comment: you have a lot of stuff copied and pasted, you can move them out to separate function. For example this: `!self.userName.isEmpty && self.userName.count > 2) && (!customField.isEmpty` is there 4 times, and it could be a one variable and so on

Comment: Clarified the problem statement and goal.

Answer (score 1):

You could employ a design pattern to keep validation layers segregated from the UI Logic.

You can follow [this](http://github.com/adamwaite/Validator) and  [this](https://medium.com/swift2go/a-better-approach-to-text-field-validations-on-ios-81bd87598070) too..

Comment: You have provided good references, but it will be good if you can actually write an answer here too. Specifically read [**Provide context for links** in How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer):  `Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline`

Comment: Thanks @SwapnilLuktuke for your feedback. Will Keep this in mind while posting an answer

Comment: What @SwapnilLuktuke mean is that you should improve _this_ answer, not just future answers